# Mujica's "Complex analysis in Banach spaces" exercise 2.M.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, polynomials, banach-spaces, multilinear-algebra

I'm trying to prove it in Mujica's book "Complex analysis in Banach spaces" which states the following. I would be grateful if someone could prove it.

Let E and F be Banach Spaces and let $P= P_0+P_1+\ldots +P_m$ where $P_j \in P_a(^jE;F)$ for $j=0\ldots,m$.

Show that the homogeneous polynomial $P_m$ is given by the formula:

$P_m(x)= \dfrac{1}{m!\; 2^m}\sum\limits_{\varepsilon_j=\pm 1} \varepsilon_1 \ldots \varepsilon_m P(x_0+\varepsilon_1x+\ldots+\varepsilon_m x) $

for all $x_0,x\in E$.

> **Notations:** A mapping $P:E \rightarrow F$ is said to be an $m$-homogeneous polynomial if there exists  $A\in L_a(^m E;F)$  such that $P(x)=Ax^m$ for every $x\in E$. We shall denote by $P_a(^m E;F) $such that  the vector space of all $m$-homogeneous polynomials from $E$ into $F$.

Comment: That is $P_a(^jE;F)$? probably explaining the notation may help others to understand your question.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I added related definition of this notation in the book.

Comment: @Mathlover: what would $x^n$ mean? There is no multiplication in a Banach space.

Comment: Author denotes by $P_a(^m E;F)$ the space of all m−homogeneous polynomials from $E$ into $F$ , i.e, the mappings $P:E\rightarrow F$ such that exists a multilinear $A:E^m\rightarrow F$ that satisfies:
$ P(x)=Ax^m=A(x,…,x)∀x\in E $